# Where do I start making a web service for wp7 to windows azure db

Tags: web-services, windows-phone-7, azure-storage

I'm writing an app which I need to store user details, location and connections in azure db but have no experience with cloud storage. I have created my azure database but not sure how to communicate with the wp7 app. Any thoughts on where to start with the web service,
Thanks, MH

Answer (score 1):

The following may point you in the right direction "Using Windows Phone with Windows Azure
" :-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh689721(v=vs.103).aspx

http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2011/08/31/building-windows-phone-applications-using-windows-azure.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As to windows phone azure project, do you mean Windows Azure Toolkit for Windows Phone? This toolkit is optional. It may help us in some cases, especially if we want to integrate with ACS. But a web service will be enough if all we need is to bring data to the phone.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Comment: No, you can create an windows phone azure project using the toolkit. But I think I need the toolkit to create my webService. Need to pass data back and forth but webService will suffice. Will post any new issues I encounter as new questions. Thanks,

Comment: We don’t have to use the toolkit to create web services. To create a service in Windows Azure, we can create a web role project using the WCF Web Role template.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Paul’s suggestions, the recommended architecture is: Hosting a service in Windows Azure (such as WCF Data Services). The service will talk to SQL Azure (if you use SQL Azure as the database). Client devices, such as Windows Phone, iPhone, Andriod, a web browser, and so on, will communicate with the service. If you use WCF Data Services, you can expose the data to clients via the OData protocol, which is supported by multiple devices. To get started with WCF Data Services, I would like to suggest you to check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668796.aspx. To learn how to consume OData in Windows Phone, please refer to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phaniraj/archive/2010/03/19/developing-a-windows-phone-7-application-that-consumes-odata.aspx.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Comment: Ok so I can just interact between phone app and azure using a web service? I don't need to create a windows phone azure project